# How these to platforms compare in performance namely staff-wsf and wt?

Tags: wt, staff-wsf

How these to c++ web service framworks compare in performance namely [staff-wsf](http://code.google.com/p/staff/) and [witty](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not perform bench marking, But can get idea from following

> Although implemented in C++, Wt’s main focus or novelty is not its
>   performance, but its focus on developing maintainable applications and
>   its extensive library of built-in widgets. But because it is popular
>   and widely used in embedded systems, you will find that performance
>   and foot-print has been optimized too, by virtue of a no-nonsense API,
>   thoughtful architecture, and C++ …

given in webtoolkit [tutorial](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/wt.html)